# How to get a reference to my Cordova iOS plugin instance?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to do something unorthodox with a custom Cordova iOS plugin. From the JS side I invoke a function which saves the callback in a memeber variable on the native side of the plugin like this:

```
-(void) setCallback:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
  _callbackId = command.callbackId; 
}
```

This is all I do. I don't fire the callback because I will want to fire it later when some condition on the native side becomes true. I wrote a separate method on the native side that does this:

```
-(void) fireCallback:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:saveStateCallbackId];
}
```

This method is not meant to be called from the JS side. Instead I want to call it when some condition on the native side becomes true. The problem is that I would like to call this method from AppDelegate.m, but how do I get a reference to the instance of my plugin so I can invoke the method?

Answer (score 2):

Silly me... I don't need all these tricks. Turns out I can just call js directly like this:

> [webview
>   stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myJavascriptFunction()"];

http://blog.techno-barje.fr//post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/

I can reference the webview from in AppDelegate like this: self.viewController.webView

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

`AppDelegate` should have a `viewController` member that allows you to access your plugin instance this way

```
PluginClass* pluginInstance = [self.viewController getCommandInstance:@"PluginName"];
```